# UITextField Clear Button not in correct position

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface

I am working on a login screen for a swift app and the clear buttons in the text fields are not positioning themselves correctly.

The clear button cannot be seen when in portrait mode and it is kind of far from the right in landscape mode (iPhone 6s emulator). On an iPad Pro, the problem is even worse, with the x a little past halfway across the field. I can't find anything that will tell me how to reset its position to be right aligned and stay on the right of the field.

I don't have a custom class for it, and the only changes from the default are to make the clear button appear when editing and to have the keyboard type set to email keyboard and have the password field have secure text entry.

[Landscape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/80G0H.png)

[Portrait](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0SA6j.png)

Comment: Since you tagged this Swift you must be creating the text field in code, correct? If so, update your question with relevant code for creating and sizing the text field.

Comment: No, it's just that the rest of the project is in swift, so any code responses I get I would prefer to be in Swift. The field is made in the storyboard.

Comment: I fixed my problem. I had to add some constraints to the text field in the storyboard and now the clear button is behaving as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I found out the problem. For some reason the constraints for the text view's parent view were throwing the clear button off its standard positioning. I added leading/trailing constraints on the text field and the clear button went right back to its default position for all cases.

Answer (score 0):

If any default solution doesn't work then you can add a view to UITextField using

> usernameTextField.leftView